# unusual way of declaring a php argument

Tags: php, methods

In the code pasted bellow the function accepts 2 arguments

I know that the first argument - `$dir` - is passed into the function when it is called and the data is accessed using the variable `$dir`.

However the second argument confuses me.
I have never seen a argument written in this way before does it set the value of `$ext` as `".php"`?
if yes why is this done in included in the arguments at all (it could be declared inside the function itself?

if no then what is it doing?

```
public static function register($dir, $ext = '.php')
{
    $autoloader = new static($dir, $ext);
    spl_autoload_register([$autoloader, 'load']);

    return $autoloader;
}
```

Comment: It's called [Default Argument Values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default). The documentation explains it way better than what a comment could say.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP you can give a default value to a function argument. In this case second argument gets the value of `.php` when ommitted like:

```
classname::register($directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set default values for parameters in php:

Calling the function like this:

```
register('some/dir');
```

will assign the default value of `.php` to `$ext`.

You can overwrite this default value by passing a second argument:

```
register('some/dir', '.txt'); // $ext will now be .txt
```